# Finding local variables on stack using crash utility

Tags: linux, crash, crash-dumps

I am using crash utility to anaylze vmcore (linux) result but i find difficulty in extracting a local variable value in the function. Googling for the same says one can use "info locals" but when i use this, it says command not found.

After searching for quite a while, found the below link which says this support is present in crash buy doing self-compilation.
http://www.redhat.com/archives/crash-utility/2009-May/msg00003.html

Are there any pointers for extracting local variables in vmcore dump?

Comment: Can someone please help me on this?

Answer (score 5):

Please look at this article describing the x86 stack frame layout:
http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/09/06/stack-frame-layout-on-x86-64/

If you are looking for function arguments please note that arguments 1-6 are passed via registers (rdi, rsi,..) and arguments 7-.. are passed on the stack.

So by definition it is very easy to see the value of arguments 7-.. - just dump the stack context:
crash> bt -f
...

```
 #6 [ffff88107fc23e08] delayed_work_timer_fn at ffffffff8108a060
    ffff88107fc23e10: ffff88107fc23e50 **ffffffff8107e329** <-- return address 
 #7 [ffff88107fc23e18] call_timer_fn at **ffffffff8107e329**
    ffff88107fc23e20: ffff88101dc6d660 ffff881020f44000 
    ffff88107fc23e30: ffff88101dc6d660 ffff88107fc23e90 
    ffff88107fc23e40: ffff881020f45020 ffffffff8108a030 
    ffff88107fc23e50: ffff88107fc23ed0 ffffffff8107e739
```

See the link. Arguments 7-.. will be pushed to the stack below the return address (here we do not have such arguments).

For arguments 1-6 which are passed via registers you must disassemble the calling function code and follow how they are getting the value. Most of the time you will see they are getting the value from another register. What you try to find is if at some point the value was read from the stack. Here is an example:

```
0xffffffff8107e723 <run_timer_softirq+307>:     sti    
0xffffffff8107e724 <run_timer_softirq+308>:     nopw   0x0(%rax,%rax,1)
0xffffffff8107e72a <run_timer_softirq+314>:     mov    -0x48(%rbp),%rdx <-- rdx = rbp[-0x48] <-- rdx is from the stack!!!
0xffffffff8107e72e <run_timer_softirq+318>:     mov    %r12,%rdi
0xffffffff8107e731 <run_timer_softirq+321>:     mov    %r15,%rsi
0xffffffff8107e734 <run_timer_softirq+324>:     callq  0xffffffff8107e2e0 <call_timer_fn>

static void call_timer_fn(struct timer_list *timer, void (*fn)(unsigned long),
                          unsigned long data)
```

So 'call_timer_fn' third argument (rdx) is what we have in the stack of 'call_timer_fn' at location rbp[-0x48]...

This is great...

If this is not the case then you have to continu down the call trace & assembly ( :-( )till you get to the first place that the registers are known:

```
#14 [ffff88107fc23fb0] apic_timer_interrupt at ffffffff81515e33
--- <IRQ stack> ---
#15 [ffff881020f75da8] apic_timer_interrupt at ffffffff81515e33
    [exception RIP: intel_idle+193]
    RIP: ffffffff812bce31  RSP: ffff881020f75e58  RFLAGS: 00000202
    RAX: 0000000000000000  RBX: ffff88107fc2e3c0  RCX: 0000000000000000
    RDX: 0000000000007cd0  RSI: 0000000000000000  RDI: 0000000001e78df8
    RBP: ffff881020f75ea8   R8: 0000000000004183   R9: 000000000000003b
    R10: 000000a89c12c7e8  R11: 0000000000000001  R12: ffffffff81515e2e
    R13: ffff88107fc2e500  R14: 0000000000000000  R15: ffff88107fc2e3c0
    ORIG_RAX: ffffffffffffff10  CS: 0010  SS: 0018
```

For local function variables, please see the link. They are pushed to the stack if not optimized. I suggest to disable optimization if you can. Now you should be able to get them from the stack.

Answer (score -2):

`info locals` is a gdb command.

You can create a coredump `(crash: dump <pid>)` of a particular process(crashed process) and load the core in to gdb (when you dump the core from inside crash, it tells you the instructions to load the gdb with the generated core).

Inside gdb, you can give `info locals` It will surely work then.